# Curly curly not recognizing quoted data

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

I'd like to feed two vectors into my custom function with `purrr:map2`. Unfortunately, when I do this, I get the error  `` Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..2`. x Input `..2` must be of size 93 or 1, not size 9. ℹ Input `..2` is `!is.na(y)`. ``

How can I get my custom function to use arguments as data and run successfully with map2?

This is a MWE:

```
library(MASS)
data(Cars93)

crosstab_3way_custom <- function(y, z) {
pollster::crosstab_3way(Cars93, 
                x = Origin, 
                y= {{ y }}, 
                z = {{ z }},
                weight = rep(1, NROW(Cars93)),
                pct_type = "row")
}

combos <- expand.grid(c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type"), c("Min.Price", "Price", "Max.Price"))
combos <- combos %>% map(as.character)

map2(combos[1], combos[2], function(y,z) crosstab_3way_custom(y,z))
```

Comment: Is `Cars93` from `MASS` package? How do you run this for one example without `map` ? `crosstab_3way(df = MASS::Cars93, x = Origin, y = Manufacturer,z = Min.Price)` This returns an error.

Comment: I didn't realize weights were required. I just added some and it should work now for the individual case. And yes, Cars93 is from the MASS package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass quoted variable use `sym` with `!!` :

```
crosstab_3way_custom <- function(y, z) {
  pollster::crosstab_3way(data, 
                          x = Origin, 
                          y = !!sym(y),
                          z = !!sym(z),
                          weight = 1,
                          pct_type = "row")
}

purrr::map2(combos$Var1, combos$Var2, crosstab_3way_custom)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I find quasiquotation difficult to wrap my head around. Could you explain for this particular case why you chose the sym function?

Comment: `{{}}` mostly work with unquoted data, here we have strings for which `sym` is helpful.

Comment: But in this case it will not work with names that are not in quotation marks? Right?